# Output sound to multiple channels of the sound card

Tags: java, audio, soundcard

I am trying to build a program in Java, which would be able to output sound to different output lines on my sound card.

[image: SCHEME]

How is it possible to do in Java?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what background you have in working with sound (it might be bigger than mine) but what I think you have is a number of lines that you want to direct to a number of ports? http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/sound/sampled/package-summary.html - This might be an API for this, which I don't know much about (I've seen a program using something like that with VoIP).
By the way if yr working on Windows, I believe that some information about your soundcard is stored in the registry, and you might have to update the registry from the program to gain access to it (not sure).

I hope I helped somehow :)

Comment: Thanks. From what I've managed to collect I think there is no way in Java to see what channels my sound card has. I am able to play sounds through it, but only on the channels set to default on my system preferences. I am on a mac by the way.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the [Java sound programmer's guide](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/sound/programmer_guide/chapter3.html#113216).

To get this to work I had to reconfigure my sound card to expose its ports as separate "outs"; otherwise the sound card would route the sound automatically depending on whether a pair of headphones were plugged in. (On Windows.)

Comment: How did you reconfigure your soundcard? I did this on Mac, but I also need it to work on Windows and haven't found a way to do so yet.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Jack](http://jackaudio.org/) (Jack Audio Connection Kit) to route sound to your soundcard. It is a little complicated, it doesn't work with pulseaudio, but you can make it work.

[JnaJack](https://github.com/jaudiolibs/jnajack) provides an interface from Java to the Jack API via JNA. It's really quite easy.

I wrote it up in more detail [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45821554/select-output-line-in-java-for-eight-channel-sound-card/46061522#46061522).